# How can I get a styled form to be submitted?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

So I'm trying to submit an HTML forms but I can't get it to work. I've tried removing some styling to different divs, and also I've tried removing javascirpt files but nothing seems to be the problem. I already checked about 10 posts here on Stackoverflow but none of them could help me. I would really appreciate if someone could help me.

```js
//Nearby Search Overlay
var state_overlay1 = true;
function nearby_search_toggle() {
  if (state_overlay1) {
    state_overlay1 = false;
    document.getElementById("nearby_search").style.height = "100%";
         
  } else {
    state_overlay1 = true;
    document.getElementById("nearby_search").style.height = "0%";
  }
}

//Search Nearby Query
var nearby_query = "¿a dónde quieres ir?";
function update_query(choice) {
  document.getElementById("nearby_query_text").innerHTML = choice;
  document.getElementById("adqi_button").style.backgroundColor = "#A288E3"; 
  nearby_search_toggle();
}

//Add Address Overlay
var state_overlay2 = true;
function add_address_toggle() {
  if (state_overlay2) {
    state_overlay2 = false;
    document.getElementById("adqi_button").style.zIndex = "0";
    document.getElementById("add_address").style.height = "100%";
  } else {
    state_overlay2 = true;
    document.getElementById("adqi_button").style.zIndex = "2";
    document.getElementById("add_address").style.height = "0%";
  }
}

function add_address(){
}
```

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: biolinum;
    src: 'fonts/LinBiolinum_R.ttf';
}
@font-face {
    font-family: biolinum;
    src: 'fonts/LinBiolinum_RB.ttf';
    font-weight: bold;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: biolinum;
    src: 'fonts/LinBiolinum_RI.ttf';
    font-style: italic;
}
body {
    background-color: #FCF7F8;
    font-size: 62.5%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
p {
    margin-block-start: 0rem;
    margin-block-end: 0rem;
}
h1 {
    margin-block-start: 0rem;
    margin-block-end: 0rem;
}
.domainhome {
    font-family: biolinum;
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: #1D263B;
    background-color: #FCF7F8;
    border: none;
    padding-top: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline:none;

    margin-top: 2rem;
    margin-left: 5rem;
}
a:link {
    color: #1D263B;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    color: #1D263B;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    margin-top: 4rem;
}
.left-bar {
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: 5rem;
}

.right-bar {
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: 5rem;
    margin-right: 5rem;

    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    
}

button {
    transition: 0.4s;
}
button:hover {
    transform: rotate(-1deg) translate(0px, -8px);
}
.adondequieresir {
    font-family: biolinum;
    font-size: 1.66rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FCF7F8;
    background-color: #1D263B;
    border: none;
    width: 275px;
    height: 75px;

    cursor: pointer;
    outline:none;

    margin-bottom: 3rem;

    z-index: 2; 
    position: relative;
}
.agregarubicacion {
    font-family: biolinum;
    font-size: 1.33rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FCF7F8;
    background-color: #1D263B;
    border: none;
    width: 275px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;

    cursor: pointer;
    outline:none;

    margin-bottom: 3rem;
}
.personasunidas {
    font-family: biolinum;
    font-size: 1.33rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FCF7F8;
    background-color: #1D263B;
    border: none;
    width: 275px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;

    cursor: pointer;
    outline:none;

    margin-bottom: 3rem;
}
.icons {
    float: left; 
    margin-left: 7px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#map {
    height: 400px;
}

#nearby_search {
    transition: 0.4s;
    position: fixed; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 0%; 
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index: 1;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    transition: 0.4s;
    backdrop-filter: blur(6px);

    -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
    scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
#nearby_search::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
.adqi_dropdown {
    margin-top: 134px;
    margin-left: 25rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
}
#add_address {
    transition: 0.4s;
    position: fixed; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 0%; 
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index: 1;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    transition: 0.4s;
    backdrop-filter: blur(6px);

    -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
    scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
#add_address::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
.square_popup {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    height: 200px;
    width: 500px;
    display: flex;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-direction: column;

    background-color: #1D263B;
    font-family: biolinum;
    font-size: 1.33rem;
    color: #FCF7F8;

    justify-content: space-evenly;

    border-radius: 50px;
}
#cancelar_button {
    height: 50px;
    width: 25%;
    border-radius: 50px;

    font-family: biolinum;
    font-size: 1.33rem;
    color: #FCF7F8;
    background-color: #F7B32B;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50px;

    cursor: pointer;
    outline:none;
}
#submit_button {
    height: 50px;
    width: 55%;
    border-radius: 50px;

    font-family: biolinum;
    font-size: 1.33rem;
    color: #FCF7F8;
    background-color: #7CD97C;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50px;

    cursor: pointer;
    outline:none;
}
.common_flexbox {
    display: flex;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
#nickname {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-radius: 50px;
    width: 90%;
    height: 50px;

    font-family: biolinum;
    font-size: 1.33rem;
    border: none;
    background-color: #FCF7F8;
    color: #1D263B;
    text-align: center;

    transition: 0.4s;
}
#nickname:hover {
    transform: rotate(-1deg) translate(0px, -8px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <a href="/"><button class="domainhome"><p>salgamos.com.mx</p></button></a>

    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="left-bar">

            <div>
                <button onClick="nearby_search_toggle()" class="adondequieresir" id="adqi_button"><p id="nearby_query_text">¿a dónde quieres ir?</p></button>
            </div>
            
            <div id="nearby_search">
                <div class="adqi_dropdown">
                    <button class="adondequieresir" onClick="update_query('restaurante')"><p>restaurante</p></button>
                    <button class="adondequieresir" onClick="update_query('café')"><p>café</p></button>
                    <button class="adondequieresir" onClick="update_query('bar')"><p>bar</p></button>
                    <button class="adondequieresir" onClick="update_query('parque')"><p>parque</p></button>
                    <button class="adondequieresir" onClick="update_query('antro')"><p>antro</p></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            

            <div>
                <button class="agregarubicacion" onClick="add_address_toggle()" id="au_button">
                    <img class="icons" src="{{url_for('static', filename='icons/noun_pin_button.svg')}}" width="30px" height="30px"/>
                    <p style="float: left;">¡agrega tu ubicación!</p>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div id="add_address">

                <form action="#" onsubmit="add_address();return false" name="get_nickname" method="POST">
                    <div class="square_popup">
                        
                        <input type="text" name="nickname" placeholder="¿cuál es tu apodo?" id="nickname" />

                        <div class="common_flexbox">
                            <button onClick="add_address_toggle()" id="cancelar_button"><p>Cancelar</p></button>
                            <button type="submit" id="submit_button" value="Submit"><p>Agregar ubicación</p></button>
                        </div>
                    
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div>
                <button class="personasunidas">
                    <img class="icons" src="{{url_for('static', filename='icons/noun_user.svg')}}" width="30px" height="30px"/>
                    <p style="float: left;">(n) personas unidas</p>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: CSS has no effect on whether a form can be submitted, unless it hides it completely. Have you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: your `add_address` submit handler is an empty, "do-nothing" function, and you also `return false;` to stop the default submission - so I'm not sure why you expect anything to happen on submit?